# Is it possible to programmatically prevent Windows from shutting down?

Tags: c#

I want develop a program to control Windows completely and prevent users from shutting down Windows. Is there a solution?

The programming language isn't important.

Edit:
users can not access power button on computer case or power cable, because of physical guards.

Comment: As long as there's a power cable, there's a way of shutting down Windows...

Comment: Some sort of hardware would be required, eg. some sort of automated weapon to kill the user and so prevent them from pulling the power plug.

Comment: Apart from which, no sane user would willingly install such software.

Comment: i disabled power button on "case", the computers are always ON and cables are protected.

Comment: My iPhone is doing a pretty good job of this since ios8, maybe you should ask this question on the iOS board

Comment: @jaywayco lol .......

Comment: If there is physical security that prevents access to the power supply, switch and cables, can you not just adjust user privileges/permissions to deny power control?

Comment: i don't want disalbe power control, just prevent from shutting down.

Comment: OK, 'adjust user privileges/permissions to deny shutdown control' then.

Comment: @MartinJames: `no sane user would willingly install such software` not "willingly", "knowingly".

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you want to write a kiosk application?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Further to the suggestion by @MartinJames , [Windows 7: Shut Down Computer - Allow or Prevent Users and Groups](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/128920-shut-down-computer-allow-prevent-users-groups.html).

Answer (score 5):

A very simple way to do this in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), C#:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
}

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

This will prevent windows from shutting down, and it will prompt you that if you want to shut down anyway or cancel it, because this application (Windows Form application) is prevented from shutting down...

Ref.: *[CloseReason Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx)*

You could also try the code below which is probably better and more efficient than the code above:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
    {
        Process.Start("shutdown", "-a");
    }
}
```

Ref.: *[Cancel a Restart or Shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725878.aspx)*

After [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista) you can not block shut down just like that. Trying to do so will cause a screen that will ask you that some application is blocking shut down and if you want to shut down anyway or cancel... The code above will let you block the shut down, but you should not completely block shut down.

A much better solution, that lets you even display a message at the screen prompt that is shown when shut down is blocked, is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public extern static bool ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(IntPtr hWnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszReason);

    private bool blocked = false;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message aMessage)
    {
        const int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011;
        const int WM_ENDSESSION = 0x0016;

        if (blocked && (aMessage.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION || aMessage.Msg == WM_ENDSESSION))
            return;

        base.WndProc(ref aMessage);
    }

    void Button1_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(this.Handle, "DONT:"))
        {
            blocked = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Shutdown blocking succeeded");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Shutdown blocking failed");
    }
}
```

Ref.: *[Windows Vista - ShutdownBlockReasonCreate in C#](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/25/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-ShutdownBlockReasonCreate-in-C_2300_.aspx)*

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  As you say, to complete the shutdown all you have to do is click the "shutdown anyway" button.  As far as being a solution that prevents the user from shutting down the system... this really isn't one.

Comment: Asker wants to block system shutdown rather than app shutdown

Comment: I think it is clear from comments to the question that it is about system shutdown, not application shutdown. Can you remove the parts of your answer that is not about application shutdown?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is not about application shutdown, well may be it is but when you shutdown your PC, all your application's will be shut down and The question was How to prevent the shutdown, and the code above does prevent shut down... My code that is about application shutdown does exactly the same thing (except for showing a message) as the code about system shutdown. So I wrote this thinking that whatever will suit the user most, because there is not a better way to do this, in my knowledge. After this question I searched for this but did not find any other better solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Run `gpedit.msc` → Computer Configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Local Policies → User Rights Assignment → Shut down the system

Find a way to remove users or groups from this group policy in the language of your choice. Maybe helpful: [Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250).