# file move and directory move failing if computer shut down

Tags: c#, windows, ntfs

The question refers to windows server 2012 / 2016 OS

can file.move to same directory can fail with deleting the original file in case of computer shut down ?

Can directory.move with sub folders and files be partially performed in case of computer shut down ? I want it to be all or nothing...

Comment: In short yes - that can happen. But it has nothing to do with NTFS (because you mentioned it), but is just about the fact that Windows will eventually kill all proceses. You need to convince Windows (or the user) that your application must run to completion in case of a shutdown (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26317983/21567) for an example and some more background information. Go from there).

Comment: of course it can fail. Start the copy and then pull the power cord -> BOOM

Comment: [Alternatives to using Transactional NTFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Assuming that you mean a *graceful* shut down, and a move within the same volume rather than a copy/delete to a different volume, the file/directory will either remain where it was or will be moved to the new location.  It will not be deleted or partially moved.  If power is lost, or if the system bluescreens, all bets are off.